# Kafka is failing to start. Getting the below error

Tags: apache-kafka

`ERROR Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/0, node already exists and owner '72067757872119809' does not match current session '72067836689711106' (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral) 2021-05-05 02:19:44.796  [INF] [Kafka] [2021-05-05 02:19:44,786] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)`

Comment: `docker compose down --remove-orphans` then `docker compose up -d` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

The error is saying a broker already is running with id=0, or that Zookeeper is corrupt because a broker did not previously cleanly shut down...

In the later case, you can attempt to use `zookeeper-shell` to `rmr /brokers/ids/0`, however, this might have more unintended consequences than preforming a restart of Zookeeper as well as the brokers

Answer (score 1):

Restart the zookeeper and the broker is fixed the issue for me.
If you using the docker-compose, you can restart simply by using

```
docker-compose restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution which works here is restart the broker and then restart the server.